# Django how to save model in view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django. I'm having an issue where I can't save my model in the views.py. The concept is to have an input field where a user can type in a name, then using request.POST.get('attribute_name') I can save my model, but it's not working. When I print a list of all the objects in that model there's nothing there, even though I don't get an error message during all of this.

template:

```
<form id="save_form" method="post" action="{% url 'project_view.views.projectz_save' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Project Name</td>
    <td><input name="projectz_name"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def projectz_save(request):
try: 
    p = Project(name=request.POST.get('projectz_name'))
    p.save()
    return redirect('http://www.google.com/')
except:
    return redirect('http://www.google.com/')
```

app urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^$', views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^$', views.projectz_save, name='project_save'),
```

)

site urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^project_view/', include('project_view.urls')),
```

I even put in some silly redirect code to google.com just to see if the views.py was even executing, but it's not working, though like I said there are no error messages, the page just refreshes. I'm sure I'm doing wrong that's easy to fix, but I'm a noobie. :D

Comment: Can you show your `urls.py`?

Comment: ok, edited them in there...thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Can you check what `action` is generating the `url` tag in your html?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I think maybe I spotted the problem. The `view` is not executing because you have defined three urls with the exact `regex` in your project `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^$', views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^$', views.projectz_save, name='project_save'),
)
```

Django match it's urls by iterating over the patterns in the way they appeared so in that file all urls will match `index`. That's probably the reason why the page appears to be refreshing. Try to modify this a little:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^register$', views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^save$', views.projectz_save, name='project_save'),
)
```

This way you can execute the `projectz_save` method in the `views.py` if the `action` of the form matches the url regex.

Hope this helps!